# can`t install whoosh alchemy

Tags: python, whoosh

I can`t seem to install whoosh alchemy for the life of me. reference: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/ . Anyway, i'm following http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world and at the part where i'm trying to install whoosh-alchemy.

I'm typing in any of these 3

```
flask\Scripts\pip install flask-whooshalchemy==0.55a 
flask\Scripts\pip install flask-whooshalchemy
flask\Scripts\pip install flask-whooshalchemy==0.55
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Downloading/unpacking flask-whooshalchemy
    Downloading Flask-WhooshAlchemy-0.55.tar.gz
    Running setup.py (path:C:\users\ray\microblog\flask\build\flask-whooshalchemy\setup.py) egg_info for package flask-whooshalchemy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\users\ray\microblog\flask\build\flask-whooshalchemy\setup.py", line 28, in <module>
    'requirements.txt')).xreadlines()],
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'xreadlines'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

 File "C:\users\ray\microblog\flask\build\flask-whooshalchemy\setup.py", line 28, in <module>

'requirements.txt')).xreadlines()],

 AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'xreadlines'
```

I have no idea how to solve this at all... I'm trying to google this but haven't found any luck whatsoever. Maybe my google-fu is just terrible. Much appreciation for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this pull request](https://github.com/gyllstromk/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/pull/18) on Flask-WhooshAlchemy's github which talks about pip installs failing due to `xreadlines` call like in your error log. Try installing it directly from github where that pull request has been merged.

Here's the command to do that - `pip install git+https://github.com/gyllstromk/Flask-WhooshAlchemy.git`